# Change image source through javascript does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the current logo of this website: https://moonstrategy.io/about/ from

https://moonstrategy.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Moonstrategy_logo_vector_main_light_final.svg
to
https://moonstrategy.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Moonstrategy_logo_vector_main_final.svg

I'm embedding this code in the webpage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>document.getElementByClassName(".tgp-exclude small").src="https://moonstrategy.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Moonstrategy_logo_vector_main_final.svg";</script>
```

I've also tried using different class names and while I'm pretty sure I tried all of them, I can either not seem to find the right one, or I am totally off with the code.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be wordpress, i would change the logo on the backend, no need to use js for that

Comment: The default setting in wordpress for the logo fits the landingpage perfectly: https://moonstrategy.io/

It does not support multiple navigations and logos based on page. Therefore I can only use one global setting and have to override when needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You included jquery, but you don't use jquery
2. There is no such thing as `getElementByClassName`, there is `getElementsByClassName`
3. `getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList and you want only one element, use `querySelector` instead.

Comment: Sadly I still cannot get it to work this way :/ 

    <script>        
        document.getElementsByClassName("tgp-exclude small light")[0].src="https://moonstrategy.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Moonstrategy_logo_vector_main_final.svg"; 
        </script>


Why should one use querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName? I read that it is much slower to load with querySelector.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong here but I think the `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements with the specified class name
So it should be something like

```js
document.getElementsByClassName(".tgp-excludesmall")[0].src =
  "https://moonstrategy.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Moonstrategy_logo_vector_main_final.svg";
```

Comment: It still won't work, because this function expects a class name without a `.` at the beginning